# How to prevent re-render of a function component containing a useEffect hook in a test

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, rerender

I am testing using jest and am rendering a mock component that contains a useEffect hook, but upon running my tests I'm receiving the error "*Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.*" How do I go about preventing the useEffect to cause a re-render and fail my tests.

Mock component is created like: `renderWithReactIntl(<Component {...mockData} />);`

I'm trying to do something such as the following to try and call it once but it doesn't seem to be helping

```
describe("<Component />", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.spyOn(React, "useEffect").mockImplementationOnce(fn => fn());
  });
```

Comment: why do you want to suppress very core React feature? This way your tests would be dramatically different from real-life scenario so they would be useless! Don't fight `useEffect`, fight condition why it's looping. I cannot give focused advice until seeing component's and test's code

Comment: Is it possible though?